# Jenkins running on VM not accessible through host os

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox

I have installed Jenkins on a VM which is accessible via 127.0.0.1:8090 on the VM after changing the default port.

I want to view Jenkins via the Host OS which should work via 127.0.0.1:8090 too but this does not work.

I am using VirtualBox and a Red Hat VM. I have added a port forward via the VirtualBox network settings mapping 8090 to 8090 but this still doesn't resolve the issue.

I don't know whether the underlying problem is within Jenkins or whether there is some config still missing. I have other services on the VM which are accessible to the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the IP address 127.0.0.1 is defined as the [loop back address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), therefore, on your VM it loops back to the VM. On your host OS it will loop back to your host

You need to reconfigure the network settings for your VM and have it assigned its own IP address.

Possibly the easiest way to do this is to add a [host only network](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) which is done through the virtualbox config page

> To change a virtual machine's virtual network interface to "host only"
>   mode:
>
> either go to the "Network" page in the virtual machine's settings
>   notebook in the graphical user interface and select "Host-only
>   networking"

Comment: With Port-forwarding configured, it should still work. We're using this setup often, and have never had any problems with it. The only possible problems I can see is either a firewall issue on the host or the VM, or if there runs another process on the same port on the host.